# in amazon Why can I not view my tomcat from the public ip address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I know that this question may already have been asked, but
Why can I not view my tomcat from the public ip address?

I created a windows instance, generated my pem, then I used the RDP windows client to access the instance, I installed java and tomcat so when I do localhost:8080 or myprivateip:8080 inside the instance I can see the tomcat, but if I try mypublicip:8080 inside or outside the instance I cannot see the tomcat.
I already put the inboud and the outbound rules to allow all traffic from everywhere, but I still cannot access the tomcat fro outside, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you configured Tomcat connector to listen to TCP connections on public IP address? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the firewall of the server, once I opened the correct ports it let the traffic outside.